# How to configure the compiler to implicitly use `unknown` instead of `any` in cases where it fails to infer type information?

Tags: typescript, implicit-typing

There's the compiler option [`noImplicitAny`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#noImplicitAny), which is described this way:

> In some cases where no type annotations are present, TypeScript will fall back to a type of `any` for a variable when it cannot infer the type.
>
> This can cause some errors to be missed, for example:
>
> ```ts
> function fn(s) {
>   // No error?
>   console.log(s.subtr(3));
> }
> fn(42);
> ```
>
> Turning on `noImplicitAny` however TypeScript will issue an error whenever it would have inferred `any`:
>
> ```ts
> function fn(s) { /*
>             ~
> Parameter 's' implicitly has an 'any' type. */
>   console.log(s.subtr(3));
> }
> ```

What I want is to configure the compiler to act even more strictly where type information cannot be inferred in cases like the above: I want it to use `unknown` at every one of these sites (instead of `any`). There's another compiler option [`useUnknownInCatchVariables`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#useUnknownInCatchVariables), which is described this way:

> In TypeScript 4.0, support was added to allow changing the type of the variable in a catch clause from `any` to `unknown`. Allowing for code like:
>
> ```ts
> try {
>   // ...
> } catch (err) {
>   // We have to verify err is an
>   // error before using it as one.
>   if (err instanceof Error) {
>     console.log(err.message);
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> This pattern ensures that error handling code becomes more comprehensive because you cannot guarantee that the object being thrown is a Error subclass ahead of time. With the flag `useUnknownInCatchVariables` enabled, then you do not need the additional syntax (`: unknown`) nor a linter rule to try enforce this behavior.

However, that only applies to the `exception` parameter in a `catch` clause.

How can the compiler be configured to fall back to `unknown` in all cases?

Comment: This doesn't seem to be possible currently — but an `implicitUnknown` option has been suggested at [ms/TS#27265](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27265).

Comment: Is there a reason to implicitly infer `unknown` instead of erroring on implicit `any`?

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73998896/how-to-configure-the-compiler-to-implicitly-use-unknown-instead-of-any-in-ca?noredirect=1#comment130657746_73998896) @caTS All the reasoning/motivation is already captured in the linked issue, but essentially — improved type safety with less configuration and less source code (which is almost always desirable in a language as verbose as TS). It would also make refactoring existing JS source without annotations safer and easier.

Comment: Since you found your own answer, do you want to write it up?

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73998896/how-to-configure-the-compiler-to-implicitly-use-unknown-instead-of-any-in-ca?noredirect=1#comment130659799_73998896) @jcalz I think "You can't" (without some kind of functional workaround) is a non-answer to any "How" question. After that suggested option is implemented (if it ever happens), then someone could provide a (canonical) answer explaining how to accomplish what I asked about.

Comment: Hmm, if something is currently impossible then "this is currently impossible" with authoritative sources [is definitely an answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/333925/2887218).  Right now the workaround here is "use `--noImplicitAny` or something".  It's not *satisfying*, but it does answer the question.

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73998896/how-to-configure-the-compiler-to-implicitly-use-unknown-instead-of-any-in-ca?noredirect=1#comment130660009_73998896) @jcalz I see — thanks for that meta link. I guess I'll create an answer for now (and hopefully a real solution will be possible one day).

Answer (score 0):

At the current time, it's not possible to enable this kind of implicit stricter type safety, but an `implicitUnknown` option has been suggested at [ms/TS#27265](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27265).